# How to change the case of the bundle id?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, app-store-connect

I have read where the case of Bundle ID is not important; however I found out the hard way that this is not true.  Now, I need to get my the case of my bundle id in XCode 4 to match the case in iTunes Connect.

This is the error I get during validation:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is NO way to solve this other than starting over with a new project with the correct name and copy the files to the new project.  Then I went to iTunes Connect and created a new app.  It now works!

Answer (score 0):

Change it in your info.plist.

But note unless they are identical case they are completely different bundles as far as iTunes is concerned.

Comment: If they are completely different bundles, then that won't work, will it?  When doing a validate, I'm getting an error that they don't match, so I figured that was the issue.  So, how do I remove the error during validate?

Comment: The bundle ID is com.phoneapps.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
I tried changing it to match iTunes, but it appears the bundle id can't be changed there...

Comment: You can either edit the PRODUCT_NAME in settings or rename it in the Xcode panel directly.  OR just type the full bundle I'd in to info.plist as com.phoneapps.myproduct

Comment: There is a ProJECT Name, but no Product_Name.. none of them can be renamed... typed in full bundle id, and it reverted to the current Product_Name (first letter upper case).. what a mess!